# Hover through js or css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, jquery-hover

Having a `div` element, I can style its bg-color through either `Javascript` or `CSS`. Is there any difference between the two, or which one should we use?

```
div:hover {background-color:gray;}
```

or

```
$( div).hover(function() {
  $( this ).css('background-color','gray');//user Jquery here

});
```

There are also many things that can be done through JQ and CSS. How do we chose which one to use?

Comment: Using CSS is always better. However if you want to use modify using JS it is better to add/remove class.

Comment: Using CSS is better also You can't change or alter the actual :hover selector through Javascript.

Comment: CSS should be the preferred option, rather than JS.

Comment: Ok, but why is it better? Just saying it is won't do me any good.

Comment: It's better to user CSS because it works in all browsers even if javascript is disabled.

Comment: @GeorgeIrimiciuc it's better simply because CSS was meant for this kind of stuff. With the JS/jQuery version is more code and it implies running the JS engine *and* the CSS engine. With CSS, it's just the CSS engine. To recap, the JS version will still need the CSS version.

There are times, though, when you'll want to modify styles from JS (usually for interactions more complex than a simple hover), but then, use JS just to change the CSS class, and add styles based on those CSS clases.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7621846/using-jquery-for-css-vs-stylesheet

Comment: Think about it you are depended on javascript and javacsipt is disabled in browser what will happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd normally use CSS simply because CSS was meant for this kind of stuff. With the JS/jQuery version is more code and it implies running the JS engine and the CSS engine. With CSS, it's just the CSS engine. To recap, the JS version will still need the CSS version.

There are times, though, when you'll want to modify styles from JS, but usually for interactions more complex than a simple hover. Even then though, you would want to use JS just to change just the CSS class, and add styles based on those CSS classes.

Let me give you a couple simple examples:

#### 1. Change text color on hover

CSS properties to change: `color`.

You'd use CSS here. In the old days this was possible just for anchor elements, so you'd have used JS here for browser like IE6. This is no longer the case though, so a pure CSS solution is fine.

#### 2. Show a tooltip on hover

CSS properties to change: `display`, `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`.

You most likely want to use JS here. The tooltip markup isn't probably a child of the hovered element, so you can't reference it in your CSS. You may go with a CSS-only solution, but that requires that every element with a tooltip to encompass markup for that tooltip. A lot of redundant elements.

JS is also needed here to calculate the exact position of the toolip relative to the element and/or cursor.

Note that this is an example where you can't use a CSS class for the listed properties. You will style the look & feel of the tooltip in CSS, but the actual positioning has to be done in JS.

Answer (score 3):

Well, that's actually a pretty interesting question. I'm trying to think of how you would even do a benchmark on something like this, especially since most of the time neither CSS or JavaScript are going to be doing really computationally intensive things on a web page.

My gut feel would say that use CSS as much as possible, but don't make it into a hard and fast rule.

```
a:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

is better semantically then

```
$('a').onmouseover(function() {
  $(this).css('background-color','green');
})
```

BUT

```
$('a').onmouseover(function() {
  if (somethingelsehappened) {
    $(this).css('background-color','green');
  }
})
```

would be difficult (though not impossible) in CSS. You could do it in this way.

```
$('a').onmouseover(function() {
  if (somethingelsehappened) {
    $(this).addClass('Green');
  }
})

a.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

This would really be a slightly more awkward way to do what could have been done in JavaScript directly, but I've been thinking about it for a couple of minutes, and even here, the right solution may very well be a CSS, for example if you were setting a lot of attributes when doing the hover.

** Please note that none of this code is expected to work, these are just for demonstration purposes only.**

Refer : [When a task can be accomplished by either Javascript or CSS, is it better to use CSS?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/when-a-task-can-be-accomplished-by-either-javascript-or-css-is-it-better-to-use)

Answer (score 2):

I'll start by answering with what I know, but I'm sure many other people know a lot more than me.

One of the reasons to use CSS over JS is that CSS allows **hardware acceleration** on **mobile devices**. Javascript on the other hand, does not. This is not so important for a simple `background-color` change, but if you were doing any sort of transition and moving of an element, it will look a lot smoother and be more responsive (e.g. when the JS is locked up with a synchronous task, the animation will still run) with CSS v jQuery/JS. (I'm trying to find an example of this, I remember seeing one about a year ago).

Another reason to use CSS over JS is that it keeps your code divided into different parts, the CSS for the styling, and the Javascript for the logic. Again, this is personal preference, but is why many frameworks are more popular than others.

On the other hand, a reason to use JS over CSS would be if you needed to filter a list, and display a style on a few elements. In this case, it would make sense to do this with Javascript. Purists would argue that you should use `.addClass('myhoverclass')` instead of `.style(attr:val)` as it allows you to use the benefits of CSS listed above.

At the end of the day, it is a matter of preference. If you are looking for raw speed, or are using intense effects, use CSS as it will perform better on mobile, and can also [be forced to use hardware acceleration on a PC](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/21/play-with-hardware-accelerated-css/). On the other hand, if it is easier for you to access an element with Javascript (e.g. filtering a list), then use Javascript.

You can see this [link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/when-a-task-can-be-accomplished-by-either-javascript-or-css-is-it-better-to-use) for more.